# Running Xcode8 Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode8

In my 13th lesson in the book "App Development With Swift" (using Xcode 8) my assignment was to build a QuestionBot app. Sometimes when I wanted to check myself I ran the simulator, and every time when I tried to run it, it asked me to "stop" and then run again. I pressed the button that stops the simulator (the square) and it said "build failed". Since then every time when I tried to run, it said the same ("build failed").

every information will be great, thank you

Comment: You need to look at and correct the errors that are preventing your app from building

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should edit your question to include the code you're working with along with what you've tried to fix the problem. You might also add the compiler error you're getting.

Comment: That's the point! There are no errors in my code and I tried to write my code again, and it didn't work.

Comment: There are errors.  That's what it's telling you.  If you post the build log, we can probably help you.

Comment: cid:F53D9CE1-3773-470D-8CD0-EC7203C04A45

Comment: That's the question answerer